# On Arch how can you set a window manager to start on boot?

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager

How would you go about getting X and a window manager to load on boot, and present a fancy-ish login screen like you would in other distros? I want to use something new to me like dwm or bspwm, but I have no experience configuring window managers from scratch.

Answer (score 9):

A window manager is what runs after you've logged in.  A graphical login screen is called a display manager.  To set up a display manager in Arch, [consult the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Manager).

It boils down to installing a display manager with `pacman`, and then

```
systemctl enable [your chosen display manager]
```